# Call NodeJS API With REACT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Hy, I try to get some data from a nodeJs API. I use react for frontend. I make my node API, I test with Postman and it work fine. When I use axios for get my data from the server I get a cors Error.

This is my axios call from react:

```
async function getMagazin(){
    return (await axios.get(URL)).data; 
}
```

And this is my node Js API:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import db from './dbConfig.js';
import Magazin from './entities/Magazin.js';
import cors from 'cors';

let app = express();
let router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', router);
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'); 
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
       res.sendStatus(200);
     }
     else {
       next();
     }});

async function getMagazin(){
    return await Magazin.findAll();
}

router.route('/magazin').get(async (req, res) => {
    res.json(await getMagazin());
})

let port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port);
console.log("API is running at " + port);
```

I try to add cors in my node API and hope the error is gone but not.

This is the error:

[image]

I try to make I debug, the api call go on the server and execute sql query, but when he return he give me that error. What I must add in my server side code for the API to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order so that cors is before api

```
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api', router);
```

Comment: `app.use(cors())` should really be on top but without a deeper look that might break something.

Answer (score 0):

When you use cors you have to indicate what domain or address can contact your api by adding it in the cors middleware like this:

```
   app.use(cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    }));
```

Comment: it work, thanks, but first in the console he give me the error, and after this he give me the data.

Comment: just once, but when I refresh works. I resolve the problem moving cors in my nodejs API on top